# Avoiding over/under fitting & validation set size

Tags: statistics

I've already posted this question on stats.stackexchange a couple days ago, maybe someone here can help.

I'm using a PLS model associated to FT-NIR spectroscopy to predict some properties of biodiesel. At the moment, I'm trying to optimize the number of factors I should use to do the calculations.

Here, obviously, too many factors will cause over fitting, while too few will cause under fitting.

I have about 500 calibration (produced in triplicate, so only ~500/3 samples) points and about 50 validation points (corresponding to 50 different samples).

My question is: is the size of my validation set big enough for me to undoubtedly (well... almost) say that the best number of factors I should use is the one that returns the lowest RMSEP?

Intuitively (given that I can get RMSEC e RMSEP not so different and obtain good corelation coefficients of real vs calculated values) I would say "yes", but I have not much theoretical basis to hold on to, (I'm a student that just had some classes on introductory "probability and statistics" and has read some papers lately. Maybe you could recommend some bibliography?) and I can imagine that this, most likely, depends on a lot of other things than just the facts I just mentioned.

Comment: Have you considered regularising your problem? You could consider using a ridge or lasso regulariser which will shrink the coefficients on the factors thereby penalising over-complex models. Should you need an explanation i can write one in a full answer  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization

Comment: @SamBhatt I'll be honest, I didn't even know what "regularization" was before you mentioned it...
I'll do some research concernig what you just said. It may be helpful

Comment: What software are you using? Most statistical software does this stuff for you.  Also this series of lectures might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-VfYXzC5ro&index=12&list=PLCA2C1469EA777F9A

Comment: @AnaSilva If the goal is to select important factors as well as avoid overfitting, then a more appropriate form of regularization is to use an $L^1$ penalty over an $L^2$ penalty as with Tikhonov regularization.  This is usually called the "LASSO," so you may want to look into that as well.

Comment: @SamBhatt I'm using a kinda speciffic software made for this kind of study: TQanalyst

I've been using it for a month now and I'm pretty sure it doesn't do this

But I guess I can extract the data and analyse it on another software (I would bet mathematica has a package that does what you and dsaxton mentioned)

Comment: @AnaSilva So R is pretty fantastic to do this stuff. If would take two/three lines to do it. If you go for ridge regression, the problem is trivial enough to solve without any clever software. Let $X$ be your independent variables in a matrix, $y$ be the dependent, then for a given $\lambda$ these are the coefficients $w=(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} X^Ty$. You can use cross validation to find the Lambda

Comment: @SamBhatt I read this [lecture](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~dp497/Lecture%20IV.pdf) . I suppose that that analysis is only valid for the model they present in equation (1)... But, that's not my case (I have something like Y_i=\beta_1 x_i + \beta_0 + \epsilon_i ... ) 
Am I wrong?

Comment: No it is valid for your model, the $\beta X$ is a matrix that contains contains $\beta x_i$ for $i=1,..,n$ and $\beta_0$ (your intercept). The $\epsilon$ is just your Gaussian error. Message my stack account and I can share my email, which can make this discussion easier